# Entity unable to generate within component tag of hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

The code is as follows:

I want to generate an entity class `TermData` which is present within the component class, but I'm unable to do that.   `TermData` isn't generated.

```
<component name="term_" class="Term">
    <meta attribute="generated-class" inherit="false">TermData</meta>
    <meta attribute="extends">Entity</meta>
    <meta attribute="scope-set" inherit="false">protected</meta>

    <property name="duration_" column="DURATION" type="int" />
    <property name="durationUnits_" column="DURATION_UNITS" type="string" length="64" />
</component>
```

I'm using hibernate-3.2.6.GA.jar, hibernate-tools-3.2.3.GA.jar with Java 8 and Ant 1.9

Answer (score 0):

Got the problem...there was other component of class  **class="Term"** written in different hbm file which was causing the problem as the genearted-class for that was "Dummy"...so once i changed generated-class at both places as same...it fixed my problem...may be it was due to the order in which it was being processed....as it already generated a component of same class , so it didn't generate the other one.